# Need help to identify a bmx

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, bmx, restoration, serial-number

I have come across a bmx that was trashed, it looks like a good quality bike and I would like to restore it and  wanted to find out if it's worth restoring or not, it still has stickers on it which says DEVILLE CYCLE on the front of the frame and on the it says TECHNIC PRECISION and NO-MERCY, it also has a serial number on the bottom of the frame which starts with GC, but I cannot find any info or pictures of this bike, it would be great if anyone can give me some info about it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It has a decoupler to allow for bar spins, so looks to have been set up as a trick bike.

Comment: @Criggie - That's common on BMX bikes in the US.

Comment: The only thing that's notable about this bike is the arrangement of the seat stays.

Comment: TBH I'm surprised it has brakes at all.  They seem to be early casualties.

Comment: Without doing to much Google, looking at the angled seat post and seat stays this could be an early Mongoose or GT or it could be something entirely different but styled like one

Comment: A (very) rusty, sad BMX.

Comment: My guess is that Deville is, or was, a bicycle shop or several bike shops in different locations that purchased enough bikes from an over seas bike maker to be able to get their own branding put on the bike and possibly define their own specifications for the bike. There is nothing in bmxmuseum.com on this brand or in any of my other sources.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you're still planning on restoring that BMX, but what I can tell you is that I have that exact same bike.
I have had mine since brand new and brought it in 1999.
I don't think it has much value so to speak, but it's been put together to compete with Mongoose.
Mine has blue chrome parts rather than the purple/pink yours has.
Does your chain gear sprocket say 'CD Compact Disk'?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  Do you remember the brand name your bike was originally sold under?  Or even where you purchased it?